# Adding of to certain declarations

Tags: grammar

Which is correct

it is not that big a deal

or

it is not that big of a deal

Why does "of" need to be added ?

Answer (score 0):

"Not that bid a deal"  is the standard form, "not that big of a deal" is an informal variant.

This informal usage often found with the adverbs  like how and too followed by a descriptive adjective, probably on the model of constructions like "how much" and "too much":

> - ***[Of](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of?s=t) is sometimes added to phrases beginning with the adverb how or too followed by a descriptive adjective:*** How long of a drive will it be? It's too hot of a day for tennis.
> - ***This construction is probably modeled on that in which how or too is followed by much,an unquestionably standard use in all varieties of speech and writing:*** How much of a problem will that cause the government? There was too much of an uproar for the speaker to be heard.
> - ***The use of "of" with descriptive adjectives after how or too is largely restricted to informal speech. It occurs occasionally in informal writing and written representations of speech.***

Dictionary.com